# removing the polygon based on checkbox toggle

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, checkbox

[please look into the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yzOu.png)

when i select the checkbox i am calling the getTerritory function from toggleTerritory(),that draws the polygon.But the problem i am facing is, i am not able to clear the polygon when checkbox is unselected.
Can anyone help me in doing this.

**toggleTerritory function is below**

```
$scope.toggleTerritory = function(item, list) {     
  var idx = list.indexOf(item);
  if (idx > -1) {
    list.splice(idx, 1);            
    //How to clear the polygon here 
  }
  else {
    list.push(item);
    $scope.getTerritory(item);//this creates the polygon
  }         
};





$scope.drowTerritory={};
    $scope.getTerritory= function (territory_id) {
                    setTimeout(function(){  
                $scope.drowTerritory= _.find($scope.territory, function(o) {

                        return o.territory_id === territory_id;
                        });
                        console.log("$scope.drowTerritory");
                        console.log($scope.drowTerritory.geometry);

                  //Edit Territory 
                        console.log("$scope.drowTerritory");
                        console.log($scope.drowTerritory.geometry);  
                        var wkt=$scope.drowTerritory.geometry.replace(/, /g, ","); 
                        console.log("wktnewwwww");  
                        console.log(wkt);


                        var regex = /\(([^()]+)\)/g;
                        var Rings = [];
                        var results;
                        while( results = regex.exec(wkt) ) {
                            console.log("wkt");
                            console.log(wkt);
                            Rings.push( results[1] );
                        }

                        var ptsArray=[];
                        var polyLen=Rings.length;

                        //now we need to draw the polygon for each of inner rings, but reversed
                        for(var i=0;i<polyLen;i++){
                            AddPoints(Rings[i]);
                        }

                        poly = new google.maps.Polygon({        
                            paths:ptsArray,
                            strokeColor: '#1E90FF',
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: '#1E90FF',
                            fillOpacity: 0.35,
                            editable: false,
                          });   
                         poly.setMap(map);



                        //function to add points from individual rings
                            function AddPoints(data){   
                                var pointsData=data.split(","); 
                                var len=pointsData.length;
                                console.log("len");
                                console.log(len);
                                for (var i=0;i<len;i++)
                                {           
                                     var xy=pointsData[i].split(" ");                
                                    var pt=new google.maps.LatLng(xy[1],xy[0]);            
                                    ptsArray.push(pt);  
                                };                  
                    }

                    },1000);    
             };
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_remove), o remove a polygon from the map, call the setMap() method passing null as the argument. In the following example, bermudaTriangle is a polygon object:

bermudaTriangle.setMap(null);

Note that the above method does not delete the polygon. It simply removes the polygon from the map. If instead you wish to delete the polygon, you should remove it from the map, and then set the polygon itself to null.

Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356978/google-maps-polygon-show-hide-toggle-with-checkbox), I think it can help you a lot.