# Display multiple polygons on Google Maps and toggle visibility of each polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to toggle the visibility of each polygon using checkbox. I tried doing that and the code works perfectly fine for only 1 polygon. However, if I apply for multiple polygons, it doesn't work.

This is the function

```
function toggleLayer(toggleLayer,id)
        {
            if ($('#'+id).is(':checked')) {
                toggleLayer.setMap(map);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleLayer.setMap(null);
            }
        }
```

and here i called the function

```
  <input id="cbx" type="checkbox" class="invisible" onClick="toggleLayer(polygn,'cbx')">
```

I'm based on:[Google Maps polygon show/hide toggle with checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356978/google-maps-polygon-show-hide-toggle-with-checkbox)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the question so we can see the code you tried for multiple polygons? Also, can you precise what you exactly mean by "it doesn't work"? Any error? If no error, what is the unexpected behavior?

Comment: @Kaddath i am trying to  visibility all polygons with an click in checkbox, this code works only for one polygon to show or to hide.   I am based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356978/google-maps-polygon-show-hide-toggle-with-checkbox

Comment: Not to be nasty, but you just repeated what's already in the question. I still see only one polygon in your code, and you haven't described what happens when you try with multiple ones.

Comment: Im sorry i didn't understand you, now i edit it @Kaddath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `polygn` var to your function, so it will only hide the last one (the one this var contains). In your loop, you put all of them in the array `polyprojectgoogle`, so this is this var you have to pass, and loop on all elements inside it. Something like this (i took the liberty to rename the function with an "s" so that it fits with its new functionality, and change the parameter name so it's not the same as the function name too):

```
function toggleLayers(layers,id)
    {
        var i, l = layers.length;
        if ($('#'+id).is(':checked')) {
            for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
                layers[i].setMap(map);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
                layers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
<input id="cbx" type="checkbox" class="invisible" onClick="toggleLayers(polyprojectgoogle,'cbx')">
```

Comment: If you can help me please

Comment: @trt You have two options then: either you create another array reserved only for the yellow polygons, and you pass this one to the function, or you test the color property of `layers[i]` in `toggleLayers`'s loop